# How to cast and manipulate ObservableCollection of unknown type

Tags: wpf, generics, casting, observablecollection

(Using .Net version 4.0)  I'm trying to create a WPF `AttachedProperty` for `DataGrids`.  The property will employ a method for moving an item in the grid's `ItemSource` from one index to another.  It assumes the grid's source collection is an `ObservableCollection`, which is safe for my purposes.  My plan is cast the `ItemSource` to an `ObservableCollection`, then use the collection's `Move` method.

But... `ObservableCollection` is generic and has no base class/interface, so what do I cast *to*?  The type parameter is irrelevant for this method, but also unknown since this is designed to work for any `DataGrid`.  I could go all the way down to `Ilist`, use `Remove` and `Insert`, but that will likely unnecessarily raise the `INotifyCollectionChanged` events, which I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: You could use reflection to figure out which type it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `ObservableCollection<T>.Move()` doesn't have any parameters of type `T`, you could bite the bullet and call `Move()` via reflection. I'd call it a kludge, others might use words that aren't appropriate for Stack Overflow, but the following compiles, works, and doesn't care at all what type `T` is.

```
ObservableCollection<int> foo = new ObservableCollection<int>()
{
    0, 1, 2, 3, 4
};

var method = foo.GetType()
                .GetMethod("Move", 
                    System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance 
                        | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public);

//  Not a bad idea to check here if method is null before calling it.

method.Invoke(foo, new object[] { 0, 2 });
```

You might want to call `Type.GetMethods()` instead and rummage through the results with LINQ, so you can guard against the rare case where you have a subclass on your hands that overloads `Move()` with different parameters.

But the `GetMethod()` and `Invoke()` calls don't care at all exactly what kind of `ObservableCollection` it is. And you'll get the single `CollectionChanged` event that you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, that works fine.  I wouldn't consider reflection too terrible of a kludge in this instance, since so much of interface binding uses it anyways.  My method is not super robust anyways.  I was afraid was gonna have to use reflection to figure out type `T` as well, so I'm relieved it's this simple.

Comment: @Tekito That's true, Binding is all about reflection. But it's usually hidden away in the back where nobody has to think about it!